# Does spark application equivalent to user code?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i want to know if spark application concept is equivalent to "user code". i mean spark application=user code or script that use the framework spark(like PySpark in python ) ?

Comment: I'm not entierly sure what you are asking but I believe this could help: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-anatomy-spark-application.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

In general - your spark scripts are the same as regular code.
But there are some differences. When you run spark most of your code is evaluated lazily and executed only on actions (like collect, show, count, etc.). But before execution under the hood these operations are optimized and might not be run at the same order as they are in script. In example - filters are shifted up the stream.
This course is good for general understanding: https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS100.1x/1T2015/course/ (of course there are other and newer resources).

And talking about Py-Spark - it is just an API to Spark framework and you might have code that is run by Python and then call Py-Spark for data processing.

Comment: all what you said i know that but my question is really simple when we say spark applications do we refer to our user  code that inside we include spark framework.

Comment: You mean - when you see tasks in application master - are these Spark or could there be Python?